# Capturing unrecognised options and unspecified option values with getopts

Tags: bash, error-handling, getopts

I have the following bash function that uses `getopts` to parse positional arguments.  Am trying to make options fail and get to print error messages.

```
pfa ()
{
 local OPTIND OPTARG
 local shortopts=":Vuhv:f:sc:"
 while getopts $shortopts arg; do
   case $arg in    
    ("f")  fvar="$OPTARG" ;;
    ("c")  cnum="$OPTARG" ;;
    ("s")  sort=1 ;;
    (":")  
      printf '%s\n' ": Argument not supplied to -${OPTARG}" 
      break
      ;;
    ("?") 
      printf '%s\n' "? Option not recognised by shortopts"
      break
      ;;
    (*)
      printf '%s\n' "Invoke \`pfa -h' for details."
      ;;
   esac
 done
}
```

I am running the two commands below, one with an unrecognised `-g` and another with a missing argument value to `-g`.  The problem is that when using `-f`, it is not tollingg me that the argument value has not been supplied.

```
tolu@flora: ~
pfa -g -c 200
? Option not recognised by shortopts

tolu@flora: ~
pfa -f -c 200

tolu@flora: ~
pfa -c 200 -f
: Argument not supplied to -f
```

Comment: In the second case, `-f` *does* have an argument -- it's the `-c` (check the value of `$fvar` after the loop). `-c` might *look* like a separate option, but since `-f` takes an argument, it's where the argument to `-f` belongs, and there's no reason an option argument cannot start with `-`, it's treated as the argument to `-f`.

Comment: The only way to get `Argument not supplied to -f` is to run `pfa -f`

Comment: You are right, `:` only works if it is at the end.  Not very useful in practice from what I see.  Does not even work with `pfa -c 200 -f -- "deiu"`.  I was also hoping `-f` would see that `-c` starts another option, which it does not.

Comment: I have the variable `shortopts=":Vuhv:sc:w:o:"` and want to remove the leading `:`.  How can I get that?